# PHP - Is there a NOT-complicated way to determine the position of a link on page?

Tags: php

I would like to write a script which determines the position of hyperlinks from other domains which link to my website. For example I want to know if the link comes from "inside an article", "inside a sidebar (left / right)", "inside the footer". The only way I can think of is to check the CSS classes which wrap the link. For example a link is inside the class "left_sidebar", then it's likely inside the left sidebar :) 
But this seems like a buggy way to determine this. This may work with well designed Wordpress themes, but will fail with many other sites.

So is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: how are you going to even define "article","sidebar", "footer" etc of a remote site ?

Comment: It's hard enough to screen-scrape when you know the exact structure of a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more creative ways to achieve what I think you're driving at. Instead of thinking in terms of *section* think of *context*. If a link resides in a p tag with a fair amount of additional text we can infer it's part of an article and not a set of links.

Combine a set of these inferences, add weight and you start building something that you can fine-tune.

Comment: Right, this seems like the better the way. But I go with @Jeremy1026 - It's not worth the work :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't really have any way to do what you want. Your proposed method, as you said, is not very reliable since web designers can name their divs whatever they want with no standards. It is probably the best way to get the information you want. I'd have to ask myself how bad I need the data, and make sure I have a good use for it once I have it before taking on the endeavour of trying to get it to work.